# Masking materials?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Right here I have two staircases that share the same materials.

[image: These two staircases share the same material]

I need one more of the same staircase, so I intend on selecting them by material and duplicating them. The only problem is that they share the same materials, so I would be selecting and duplicating both of them, which I don't want.

Is there a way I can "mask out" the other materials on the boat so that I can just use a box select without selecting any other materials? That way I can just box/circle select one of the stairways and not both.

The alternative is manually selecting every face of one of the stairways, which takes a very long time, and I'm sure there is a faster way to do it.

PS: If this masking doesn't exist, but there is another function that can also fix my problem, that would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: I just thought about it, and I realized I can separate the stairs, edit them, and then reattach them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two other solutions as well. The first is hide the objects that you don't want to select using the eye tools or alternatively, in edit mode, if you select just one vertex of the object you need and hit 'L' or cntrl+L you can select that item only.